# Swift: Property observer with a global variable

Tags: ios, variables, swift, properties, appdelegate

I have **two files**, and in one of them, a variable is set '*on button click*'.

```
class Home: UIViewController {

    var swipeNumber = 99

    @IBAction func pressedThreeSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
        swipeNumber = 3
    }
}
```

Then in a second file (*which acts as a second view*), I have a **didSet property observer** that is *checking for a change in the variable `swipeNumber`*.

```
func didMoveToView(view: UIView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var menu = Home()

    var swipeNumber: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            println("\(menu.swipeNumber) should be three.")
        }
    }
}
```

However, *when you run the program*, the **println line does not operate**, **suggesting that the variable swipeNumber hasn't been changed**.

So I thought that this would be a problem with the `= 0` in the property observer, but if I remove that, I receive an error about having no initialisers.

However, *after double checking*, I realised what (I think) the problem is. As the didSet code doesn't actually 'do anything', I knew that **it was not recognising a change in the variable**. I think **this is because the button is clicked and the variable 'changed' before the view loads**, i.e. *the variable has to be changed with the second view is open*. I think the problem is *where I am putting the property observer*. Perhaps I should put it in AppDelegate or somewhere else, and link that to my second view?

Any advice you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1:** Following @utahwithak's advice, I put a property observer inside the AppDelegate file:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var swipeNumber: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            println("\(swipeNumber)")
        }
    }
}
```

I also **changed `menu` to be appDelegate**. Now I get the message '3' when I press `pressedThreeSwipes`. However, when I go to the next view and play, a different message tells me that swipeNumber = 0. I think this is to do with the *first line of the property observer in my AppDelegate file*. Thank you.

Comment: Just add a new File to your project supporting files (Swift source), name it Main.swift and declare you var there.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Thank you for the suggestion. Please could you explain what to do and how this would help? Thanks

Comment: command-N and select iOS or OS X source > Swift File

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Yes I know how to create a file, I was wondering how to declare the var, link it to my second view and property observer, e.t.c.

Comment: Just don't declare it inside your view controller

Answer (score 2):

In the first file it is setting the local member variable that has no `didSet` This is a different `swipeNumber` than in your second file and setting that will not fire the didSet in the second file.

In file 2 is it a copy paste error or are you declaring `menu` and `swipeNumber` inside your function? If they are in the function that is very likely the wrong spot, they should be at the same level of your function for a class member or outside the class declaration for a global variable.

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish but if you want file 2 to be aware of file 1 information there are many ways without using a global variable. Such as a delegate that file 1 calls on a `didSet` or posting an `NSNotification` through `NSNotificationCenter`

Edit for Delegate example

in file 1 you could have something like this outside your class declaration

```
protocol SwipeNumberDelegate{
    func swipeNumberChanged(newVal:Int)
}
```

then inside your file 1 class would have something like this

```
class Home: UIViewController {
    var swipeDelegate:SwipeNumberDelegate? = nil
    var swipeNumber = 99{
         didSet{
            if let delegate = self.swipeDelegate{
                delegate.swipeNumberChanged(self.swipeNumber)
            }
         }
    }
 ...
}
```

somehow from file 1 or file 2 you have to then set  `swipeDelegate`

and in File 2 in your class declaration you'll have to say it conforms to the protocol by making it look something like:

```
class mySecondClass:SuperClass, SwipeNumberDelegate
```

and implement the protocol

```
func swipeNumberchanged(newVal:Int){
    println("Number Changed:\(newVal)")
}
```

Comment: I am interested in your idea of a delegate. Do you think that you could edit your answer to include a fix with a delegate. Thanks